# How to run RSpec using HtmlFormatter? Getting "private method `puts' called for nil:NilClass"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, rspec2, rspec-rails

I have a number of specs, which i wish to use in a Rails view (v3.2.15).

I'm using the `rspec-rails` gem v2.14.0, and the code i run is below.

This code used to work on v2.11.4 of the gem and I can see `HtmlFormatter` has now had some of its code split out into `HtmlPrinter`, which i imagine has something to do with the error. How are you meant to use `HtmlFormatter`? I can't find any documentation beyond the source code... What am i doing wrong below?

```
  class RSpecRunner
    attr_accessor :summary, :html, :documentation
    SpecPath = "system_checks/**/*_spec.rb"
    DataChecks = "data_checks/**/*_spec.rb"

    def initialize(path)
      @html = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(nil)
      @documentation = RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter.new(nil)
    end

    def run!
      RSpec::world.reset
      Dir[@spec_path].each { |f| load f }

      @html = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(nil)
      reporter = RSpec::Core::Reporter.new(@html)

      RSpec::world.example_groups.each do |example_group|
        example_group.run(reporter)
      end
    end
  end
```

**Controller**

```
@sys_check = RSpecRunner.new(RSpecRunner::SystemChecksPath)
@sys_check.run!
```

**View**

```
@sys_check.html.output.string
```

**Error**

```
NoMethodError: private method `puts' called for nil:NilClass
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/formatters/html_printer.rb:23:in `print_example_group_start'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/formatters/html_formatter.rb:50:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:127:in `block in notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:126:in `each'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:126:in `notify'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/reporter.rb:74:in `example_group_started'
    from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-2.14.7/lib/rspec/core/example_group.rb:367:in `run'
    from (irb):11:in `block in irb_binding'
    from (irb):10:in `each'
    from (irb):10
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The HtmlFormatter wants a way to output stuff. Give it STDOUT:

```
@html = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(STDOUT)
```

If you want the output to go to a file however, such as an HTML file, give it a file handle:

```
fh = File.open('path/to/html_output/rspec-html-output.html', 'w')
@html = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(fh)
```

Now you'll have a nice little html file of rspec's formatted output.

Edit:
Whatever you pass to `RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new` needs to respond to `puts` and `flush`.

Since you want to save the output to accessors you can define those methods on your own custom classes that will save the output to the appropriate accessors :html and :documentation:

```
class HTMLOutput
  def initialize(rspec_runner)
    @rspec_runner = rspec_runner
  end

  def puts(html)
    @rspec_runner.html ||= ""
    @rspec_runner.html << html
  end

  def flush; end
end

class DocOutput
  def initialize(rspec_runner)
    @rspec_runner = rspec_runner
  end

  def puts(html)
    @rspec_runner.documentation ||= ""
    @rspec_runner.documentation << html
  end

  def flush; end
end

class RSpecRunner
  def initialize(path)
    # I assumed you wanted to save the output of the formatter to the 
    # accessors :html and :documentation but you were already assigning
    # the formatters to these accessors via @html etc. Make new instance vars
    # for these and use the accessors just for the output.
    # By instantiating these output classes and passing in self they will be able
    # to save the output to the :html, :documentation accessors.
    @html_formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(HTMLOutput.new(self))
    @documentation_formatter = RSpec::Core::Formatters::DocumentationFormatter.new(DocOutput.new(self))
  end

  ... rest of your code ...
end
```

Finally, in your runner's `run!` method you don't need to instantiate this guy again:

```
@html = RSpec::Core::Formatters::HtmlFormatter.new(nil)
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks but i want to store the HTML in an attr_accessor so i can print  it in a view, send it in an email etc etc. Ill update the question to show the full code. Thanks for the response

Comment: This looks awesome. Will have a play now and get back to you. Thanks so much for the help